# How to strip ${1} in php preg_replace?

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace sources(src) for script and img tags. I have '../filename.js' and I want to get rid of 2 dots, how do I do that?

```
<?php

$file_path = content_url() . '/help/WS/WAS_B.htm';

$contents = wp_remote_fopen( $file_path );

$help_path = content_url() . '/help/';

$find = array(
    '#<script type="(.*?)" src="(.*?)">(.*?)</script>#is',
    '/<img src="(.*)" alt="(.*)" style="(.*)" \/>/i'
);

$replace = array(
    '<script type="${1}" src="' . $help_path . ' ${2}"></script>',
    '<img src="' . $help_path . '${1}" alt="${2}" style="${3}" />'
);

$preg_rep = preg_replace($find, $replace, $contents);

?>
```

This is a link and image I'm working on:

```
<img src="../Links/WAS_PIC_ControlBox-1-2-3.jpg" alt="WAS-Betjeningsboks-1-2-3" 
style="border: none; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" border="0">

<script type="text/javascript" src="../ehlpdhtm.js"></script>
```

The output I'd like to get should be like:

```
<img src="http:xxx.com/wp-content/help/Links/WAS_PIC_ControlBox-1-2-3.jpg" alt="WAS-Betjeningsboks-1-2-3" 
style="border: none; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" border="0">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http:xxx.com/wp-content/help/ehlpdhtm.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why from $1? At any rate, you may get rid of the dots by not capturing them, something like `src="(?:\.\.)?(.*?)"`

Comment: Check [this code](https://3v4l.org/tBQjR).

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew you had a genius idea, I knew solution to this would be simple

Comment: That is not that simple, I added a lot of minor fixes to the solution. Please compare my full demo to your current code. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may "trim" what you get into a backreference by *excluding* that part from the corresponding capturing group:

```
(?:\.\./)?(.*?)
```

will match and *not capture* `../` and will capture the rest into the group.

Here is the code fix:

```
$find = array(
    '#<script\s+type="(.*?)"\s+src="(?:\.{2}/)?(.*?)">(.*?)</script>#is',
    '#<img\s+src="(?:\.{2}/)?(.*?)"\s+alt="(.*?)"([^>]*?)/?>#i'
);

$replace = array(
    '<script type="${1}" src="' . $help_path . '${2}"></script>',
    '<img src="' . $help_path . '${1}" alt="${2}"${3} />'
);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/tBQjR):

```
$help_path = 'http:xxx.com/wp-content/help/';
$contents = <<<MYVAR
<img src="../Links/WAS_PIC_ControlBox-1-2-3.jpg" alt="WAS-Betjeningsboks-1-2-3" 
style="border: none; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" border="0">

<script type="text/javascript" src="../ehlpdhtm.js"></script>
MYVAR;

$find = array(
    '#<script\s+type="(.*?)"\s+src="(?:\.{2}/)?(.*?)">(.*?)</script>#is',
    '#<img\s+src="(?:\.{2}/)?(.*?)"\s+alt="(.*?)"([^>]*?)/?>#i'
);

$replace = array(
    '<script type="${1}" src="' . $help_path . '${2}"></script>',
    '<img src="' . $help_path . '${1}" alt="${2}"${3} />'
);

$preg_rep = preg_replace($find, $replace, $contents);
print_r($preg_rep);
```

Output:

```
<img src="http:xxx.com/wp-content/help/Links/WAS_PIC_ControlBox-1-2-3.jpg" alt="WAS-Betjeningsboks-1-2-3" 
style="border: none; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" border="0" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http:xxx.com/wp-content/help/ehlpdhtm.js"></script>
```

Comment: I see corrections in $find, this works very well, thanks